# How to get ids of hidden nodes

Tags: javascript, vis.js

it's possible to get hidden nodes or edges??
i tried to get by making a filter but it doesn't work becaus there is no property hidden in edges dataset.
Thanks.

```html
    var HidenEdgesIds = edges.getIds({
                           filter: function (item) {
                              return ((item.hidden == true);
                          }
                      });
```

this is a part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of [DataSets](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html) and [Edges](http://visjs.org/docs/network/edges.html) something like that should work (*untested*):

```
var hiddenEdgeIds = edges.getIds({
  filter: function (item) {
    return item.hidden == true;
  }
});
```

**Update**

Do you set the hidden property, when you add the edges to your dataset?

Comment: I tried it. But it didn't for so when I update the edge like this:
edges.update({id: edgeIds[i], hidden: true});
I copy the id in golbal vriable so that I have all ids of my hidden edges in the network like this:
HidenEdgesIds.push(edgeIds[i]);
tanks :)

Comment: yeah, this is a workaround, but vis.js should provide a cleaner solution for that. i'll try the code later.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden nodes are... hidden. It's something used *internally* in the Network to render beautifully curved edges.

Why do you need access to the hidden nodes?

UPDATE: if I understand you correctly you have two types of nodes, one of which you can toggle to be displayed or hidden. To achive that, you can simply create your nodes with ids you choose, and to show/hide them update the nodes `hidden` property. You should not try to use the internally used hidden nodes, but simply create your own group with nodes that you toggle visible/hidden.

Comment: Hi in fact I work in a project to display Malware activities so I need to hide some nodes and display them. but to display them I need to know there Ids.
thanks

Comment: In fact I can't create nodes with my own ids because I import them from a gpickel graph. So what I did is that: every time when I update the node to hidden I save their Id in a List (globale variable ) so that I know exactly all hidden nodes and I can toggle to be displayed 
thanks